# Dynamic GUI Builder

Tags: software-development, java

I am currently programming a forum-like interface in the Java programming language. For GUI making I'm using the GUI builder that comes with NetBeans (Matisse). It's a very good GUI builder for most things, but I'm wondering if there is a "dynamic" GUI builder. This would allow me to have the GUI builder add components when certain requirements are filled, but not take up space when they are not there. (So not just using the .isVisble method).

I doubt this exists, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Can you express what do you mean exactly about `Dynamic` ?

Comment: @AminSaghi I mean something like adding posts to a thread. When you add a post, it appears on the screen, pushing the bottom elements down, but before you have posted, the space isn't taken up and the bottom elements are higher up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in early phases of your project, I advice you to stop developing your project and start using [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com) portal.

If so, the effort of being dynamic have been limited to creating objects named `portlet`s

**Edit:**

`Liferay` is written in java and it's an enterprise portal. It's capable of using in small businesses to large enterprises. And you can use it and extend it for your purposes.

Comment: I need the program to be in Java, it's for school. A website won't work. I can do this with code (I even have), but I wondered if there was a way to do it without code. Even if Liferay works in Java, there are backend things I want to be able to do using java.

Comment: @DonyorM `Liferay` is written in java and it's an enterprise portal, very much capable and huger than your needs...! It's capable of using in small businesses to large enterprises. And you can use it and extend it for your purposes

Comment: You might want to mention that in the post. Thanks, though, I'll give this till tomorrow before I award the bounty. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: I also want something a little less complicated than that. It turns out that what I want to do is fairly easy to do in the code and it works fine.